# How to replace %variables% in translation using plain text with html code?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to get this result:

> Hello! Please, **Register** or **Login**!

(Bold text represents links `<a href="..."></a>`).
I would like to translate this text but I don't know how to do this with HTML.

I tried this method:

**messages.en.yml:**

```
translation:
    message: Hello! Please, %Register% or %Login%!
    register: Register
    login: Login
```

**index.html.twig:**

```
{{ 'translation.message'|trans({
      '%register%': '<a href="#">'~'translation.register'|trans~'</a>',
      '%login%': '<a href="#">'~'translation.login'|trans~'</a>'
}) }}
```

But this method return plain text and HTML code doesn't work! I tried with **|raw** option but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are meeting escaping issues.

In your case, you can use the `|raw` filter:

```
'%register%': ('<a href="#">'~'translation.register'|trans~'</a>')|raw,
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/0g5xei).

But a better practice would be to use several translations and only translate labels, such as:

```
foo.hello = 'Hello, please'
foo.register = 'register'
foo.or = 'or'
foo.login = 'login'

{{ 'foo.hello'|trans }} <a href="#">{{ 'foo.register'|trans }}</a> {{ 'foo.or'|trans }} <a href="#">{{ 'foo.login'|trans }}</a>!
```

That's less clean, but that's safer.